# Confusion on Elixir with correct Phoenix version combination

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Currently, I'm using Elixir v0.15.1 and checkout the latest verion (v0.4.0) of phoenix and tried to create a project. But, I am getting the below error message when I was running the command **mix do deps.get, compile**. I'm worried about the verions which are suitable for the elixir version. It's not documented anywhere.

How can I choose the correct versions for each other?

> **(Mix) You're trying to run :phoenix on Elixir v0.15.1 but it has**
>   **declared in its mix.exs file it supports only Elixir ~> 1.0.0-rc1**

**Note:** I was facing this issue in couple of times before with different combination versions.

Answer (score 3):

Phoenix is saying that you need Elixir at least 1.0.0-rc1 so you need to update your Elixir version. Note though that many package managers consider (correctly) "-rc1" to be a pre-release, so you may need to provide a special flag to install it. For example, in homebrew, you need to do `brew install elixir --devel`.